# Engine Warning Light of dash?

Tags: oil-leak, oil-filter

I have a Holden Cruze 2009 CDX. I have discovered a leak coming from ky oil filter and its lnding on the exhaust pipe causing a light oil smell. I also have an engine warning light that displays, my question is, would an oil filter leak cause the engine light to come on? Thanks

Comment: Which engine light, the `Check Engine` or the `Check Engine Oil` light?

Comment: Its the orange check engine light

Answer (score 1):

Oil dropping on the exhaust pipe does not normally cause any warnings on the engine management system. If the oil leak is from the filter seat then tighten it. If tight try undoing and putting some grease on the seal then tightening. If the car has oil on the dipstick then take it to your friendly mechanic to have the fault codes read from the computer.